# What is the name of the thing (awning) that we find over a car's windows?

Tags: word-request

*Request to the OP - Kindly confirm the image. This'll help you getting a correct answer.*

**What is the plastic part over a car window called?** Something like an awning.

I do not know what to call it.

[image]

No Google results. so please help me.

Comment: You may upload an image for better understanding or else this question is likely to be closed stating 'unclear' what are you asking.

Comment: *a thin film* that saves you from the sun rays or simply to avoid the vision from outside?

Comment: Picture, drawing or a more specific description, please.

Comment: Are you talking about [these things](http://www.carid.com/1999-ford-f-250-deflectors/avs-ventvisors-280676.html?gclid=CL-pqs-Zt74CFesDOgod2WwAYQ)?

Comment: @Codeswitcher Yes, I guess he means that. And I hope the OP's aware of *on* and *over* that I misunderstood ;)

Comment: @Codeswitcher Put it as an answer (deflectors) please. It's clear now. Also, kindly retract the vote.

Comment: @MaulikV What vote needs retracting?  Was that to my address?  I don't think I voted for anything here.

Comment: @Codeswitcher Aw. I think you did vote (like others and I did!). The question was *certainly* unclear before the OP responded. Sorry!

Comment: @username901345 the correct word is *mounted* as I edited in Codeswitcher's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are referred to variously as "vent visors", "[car] window deflectors", and "rain guards", as per [this vendor's website](http://www.truckchamp.com/vent-visors).

> [Window deflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_deflector) - A window deflector is mounted above the doors of some automobiles, **to protect the inside of the car from rain** or other precipitation in case of slightly opened windows.